# Accessing multiple level maps using for_each

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am struggling to use `for_each` to walk through a multi-level variable map.

```
# ./vars.tfvars

application_services = {
  chat = {
    name              = "chat"
    location          = "eastus"
    resource_group    = "rg02"

    site config = {
      health_check_path                 = "/health"
      health_check_eviction_time_in_min = "4"
    
    }
  }
}
```

```
# ./main.tf

resource "azure_windows_web_app" "windows_web_app" {
  for_each        = var.application_services
  name            = each.value.name
  location        = each.value.location
  resource_group  = each.value.resource_group

  site_config {
    health_check_path   = 
    health_check_eviction_time_in_min = 
  }


}
```

In main.tf, I have tried to put `each.value.site_config.health_check_path`, but this does not work because `for_each` only walks through the top level.

How do other people solve this?

I had been just setting the `site_config` settings at the `chat` level, forgetting about the fact that they were nested, and then just using `each.value.health_check_path`.  This works fine for the azurerm_windows_web_app resource, but does not scale to the azurerm_application_gateway resource, where I need the ability to define several "site_config" style blocks, and in some cases I need to be able to provide more than one of a given block, like `backend_https_settings`  I had been hoping to provide a structure like this:

```
./vars.tfvars

application_gateway = {
  gw01 = {
    name              = "gateway01"
    location          = "eastus"
    resource_group    = "rg02"

    backend_https_settings = {
      name            = "http"
      path            = "/"
      port            = 80
      protocol        = "Http"
      request_timeout = 60    
    }

    backend_https_settings = {
      name            = "https"
      path            = "/"
      port            = 443
      protocol        = "Https"
      request_timeout = 60
    }
  }
  
  gw02 = { ... }
}
```

I am aware that I have not provided specific error messages, but that is largely because I have not yet run this code, and these example files I have posted are incomplete.  I just need to know how to access blocks inside for_each, or if there is a better way to skin this cat, I am open to making the switch.

Thanks in advance

Bill

Comment: "but this does not work because for_each only walks through the top level." - what does it even mean? What errors do you actually get? how do you know if it does not work if you even haven't run the code?

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> In main.tf, I have tried to put each.value.site_config.health_check_path, but this does not work because for_each only walks through the top level.

However, this is not true.

Consider the code below:

```
locals {
  application_services = {
    chat = {
      name           = "chat"
      location       = "eastus"
      resource_group = "rg02"

      site_config = {
        health_check_path                 = "/health"
        health_check_eviction_time_in_min = "4"
      }
    }
  }
}

output "health_checks" {
  value = { for key, application_service in local.application_services : 
    key => application_service.site_config.health_check_path
  }
}
```

This code is correct and the output is:

```
health_checks = {
  "chat" = "/health"
}
```

Are you sure your problem is not a simple typo? You have "site config" instead of "site_config" in `./vars.tfvars` file.

Then the `each.value.site_config.health_check_path` should work like charm on `main.tf`.